# Disable iframe textarea

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an Iframe that is editable as part of a WYSIWYG editor I'm making for fun. I want to be able to disable typing in the editor when a button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
<a class="buttonOnBar_break" id="btn1" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iBold();"  title="Bold text"><img id="btnOnBarImg"src="img/icons/bold.png"></a>

<textarea style="display:none;"id="postTextStyle" name="Text" cols="100" rows="14" wrap="hard" ><?php echo $text;?></textarea>
<center><iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" ><?php echo $text;?></iframe></center>

<script>
  function iBold(){ 
     document.getElementById("richTextField").disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

This does not work for me. I have searched the internet for an hour and a half now trying to find a solution but everything i have tried has not worked. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

To disable editing of an iframe, one must edit its document's [`designMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/designMode) flag

```
// 'on' to enable it
document.getElemwentById('richTextField').contentDocument.designMode = 'off';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong element to disable - you need to disable the textarea if you want to disable input:

```
document.getElementById("postTextStyle").disabled = true;
```

That said, your text area appears to be currently hidden via `display:none` so which element are you using as the input?

Comment: i do believe the iframe is the element being used for input